# Import not working in magento 2.4.6 and category product disappeared

Tags: category, import, products, importexport, category-page

When i am importing a csv file in magento 2.4.6. It is giving me this error again and again

```
Additional data: <div class="messages"><div class="message message-error error"><div data-ui-id="messages-message-error" >Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /chroot/home/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog-import-export/Model/Import/Product.php on line 1721</div></div></div>
```

Also some imports are working and some are giving this error. Also when i imported a file when it got imported all the other products from category disappeared and only imported products remain. I can make sure that the csv file is valid one. I tried reindexing but having same issue. The  error i am encountering is listed above.This is line   `foreach ($websiteData as $delSku => $websites) { $productId = $this->skuProcessor->getNewSku($delSku)['entity_id']; $delProductId[] = $productId;` Please help!

Comment: I checked in admin and found that the category of the products are not assigned . I assigned it previously and now there is no category selected. I am not sure how this has happened

Comment: Before Import, what you have selected into "Import Behavior" ?

Comment: I have selected add/update .